# Error while parsing table data using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to get the entries populated in a table which can be found with soup.findAll('table',{'id':'taxHistoryTable'}) in the HTML page. Now I need to create a pointer similar to this with in this soup so that I can get the values in

```
<table id="taxHistoryTable" class="view-history responsive-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized ceilingless"><thead>
<tr><th class="year">Year</th>
<th class="numeric property-taxes">Property taxes</th>
<th class="numeric">Change</th><th class="numeric tax-assessment">Tax assessment</th>
<th class="numeric">Change</th></tr></thead><tfoot>
<tr><td colspan="5"><span class="yui3-toggle-content-link-block"><a href="#" class="yui3-toggle-content-link">
<span class="maximize">More</span><span class="minimize">Fewer</span></a></span></td>             </tr></tfoot><tbody>
<tr class="alt"><td>2011</td><td class="numeric">$489</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value"><span class="inc">-81.8%</span></span></td>
<td class="numeric">$34,730</td>
<td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value"><span class="inc">-6.9%</span></span>   </td></tr><tr>
<td>2010</td><td class="numeric">$2,683</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value"><span class="dec">177%</span></span></td><td class="numeric">$37,300</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value"><span class="dec">98.7%</span></span></td></tr><tr class="alt"><td>2009</td><td class="numeric">$969</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value">--</span></td><td class="numeric">$18,770</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value">--</span></td></tr><tr class="minimize"><td>2008</td><td class="numeric">$0</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value">--</span></td><td class="numeric">$18,770</td><td class="numeric"><span class="delta-value">--</span></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

which is within the table class entry taxHistoryTable. I wrote 2 loops to exactly identify the places and then tried to assign it to a variable name and then write it to a CSV file.

```
        page = urllib2.urlopen(houselink).read() #opening link
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page) #parsing link
        address = soup.find('h1',{'class':'prop-addr'}) #finding html address of house address
        price = soup.find('h2',{'class':'prop-value-price'}) #finding html address of price info, find used to find only instance of price
        price1 = price.find('span',{'class':'value'}) #Had to do this as price address was not unique at granular level, used upper level to identify it
        #Price address was not unique becuase of presence of Zestimate price also on page
        bedroom = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'prop-facts-value'})[0]
        bathroom = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'prop-facts-value'})[1]
        #zestimate
        zestimate = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'zestimate'})[1]
        #tax
        loop1 = soup.findAll('table',{'id':'taxHistoryTable'})
        for form1 in loop1:
            loop2=form1.findAll('tr',{'class':'alt'})
            for form2 in loop2:
                #year1=form2.find('td')[0]
                tax1=form2.find('td',{'class':'numeric'})[0]
                percent1=form2.find('span',{'class':'inc'})[0]
                asses1=form2.find('td',{'class':'numeric'})[1]
                precent2=form2.find('span',{'class':'inc'})[1]
 try:
            q_cleaned = unicode(u' '.join(zestimate.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip()
        except AttributeError:
            q_cleaned = ""
        try:
            r_cleaned = unicode(u' '.join(tax1.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip()
        except AttributeError:
            r_cleaned = ""
        try:
            s_cleaned = unicode(u' '.join(percent1.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip()
        except AttributeError:
            s_cleaned = ""
        try:
            t_cleaned = unicode(u' '.join(asses1.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip()
        except AttributeError:
            t_cleaned = ""
        try:
            u_cleaned = unicode(u' '.join(percent2.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip()
        except AttributeError:
            u_cleaned = ""

        spamwriter.writerow([a_cleaned,b_cleaned,d_cleaned,e_cleaned,f_cleaned,g_cleaned,h_cleaned,i_cleaned,j_cleaned,k_cleaned,l_cleaned,m_cleaned,n_cleaned,o_cleaned,p_cleaned,coordinates,q_cleaned,r_cleaned,s_cleaned,t_cleaned,u_cleaned]) #writing row for that address price combination
```

The actual code i am working on is very long so I have only included the pieces specific to the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tax1' referenced before assignment" which i am receiving.

Can someone help me understand how to assign these variable such that the value in those is available after the loop is done.

Comment: Does "tax1" appear earlier in your code? If so, can you post those lines? Also, are you sure your code is reaching the line in which you define "tax1" when you get this error message?

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to locate after `zestimate`, like `tax`..etc are all empty tags from `urllib2` response. In a short word, `loop1 = soup.findAll('table',{'id':'taxHistoryTable'})` will find nothing because its parent is an empty `div` tag if you are making request using urllib2 or mechanize. So your code after that will sure not work.

To collect the complete HTML source_code as you can see in the browser, you need a tool that can handle javascript etc..and function like a real browser, then you can will [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ghost.py phantomjs...etc.

btw, since you are trying to scrape zillow. You had better check out their API before firing up your robot. Good luck.